# How to expand row in angular with same number of columns as parent row

Tags: angular-material, expandable-table

I followed this link https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-12-table-with-multiple-expanded-rows-example/  for expandable row but it is not working for same number of columns.
Can anyone plz help.
I need to show like this[image]

Answer (score -1):

For same number of columns, you can have same template as you have for your parent table in your **expandedDetail** definition.

May be you can take reference from here [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping-expand-sort?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).